# Unable to run React Native Project on simulator after updating to Xcode 12

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

I just updated to Xcode 12 and now my react native project (which was working just before updating) will not run and outputs this error

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
info Launching "app.lfgo.release"
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=4):
The request to open "app.lfgo.release" failed.
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "app.lfgo.release"
    Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "app.lfgo.release"
```

Answer (score 5):

The same was happening to me when upgraded to Xcode 12. What helped was to (if using lock files) install @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios as devDep and bump version in all `@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios` entries in yarn.lock file to 4.13.0

Comment: I have the same error but i am using ionic 5 / cordova / angular any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this fixed it for me or anything about it but...

Using `npx react-native run-ios` throws this error for me, but when i built through xcode it worked fine. Makes no sense to me but oh well...

Comment: I fixed the `npx` command removing the `react-native` package and readding it, be sure to readd it using the same version you previously had. This action updates the underlaying dependency `@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios`, which is the actual fix for this issue.

Comment: @AndrésTorresMarroquín Thanks! That fixed my problem!